# Use of a long-running 'develop' branch with Git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

A question related to good practices for managing a big project with Git: I hear that it is common practice to have a `develop` branch, where you do your development, to keep the `master` branch only for stable/production versions.
**My question is: why is this needed?** I'm not asking for opinions/debates, but for the pros and cons for such a technique.

The problem for me is that it mixes two concepts: version system, and release system. When you have a stable/production version, you should mark it with a tag - this would be a release. Anything else is obviously under development.

It's even less clear to me, as it is common practice to have `feature` branches. Once your `feature` branch is stable, what is the point of merging it into a `develop` branch, rather than into the `master` branch directly? Again, in my mind, only `tags` should be used to show stable releases, not a specific branch. And so, for me it would be OK to have unstable code in `master`, following a merge with a `feature` branch.

I would add that on GitHub, the release mechanism is based on `tags`, it is not based on `push` actions in a specific branch; for me, this is again a point against the use of a `develop` branch.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're referring to the workflow know as [Git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)?

Comment: Exactly, see also https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for it is when you have a bleeding edge release. The logic is as follows:

- Master always has stable code that contains new stable features that are not present in the last stable release but suitable for use in development environments
- Tags show a milestone, a stable production-ready release
- Development branch contains buggy features under active development and not suitable for use in development environments

Comment: Shouldn't buggy features rather be in their own `feature` banches?

Comment: Feature branches are for feature development. They may however create regression errors or create issues with other features which may not be apparent until both get merged to the development branch

Comment: If the `feature` branch is rebased using `master` before the merge, why should there be any errors at this stage?

Comment: Suppose there are two developers who use the same base to develop two different features. How do you know both are compatible? Both the pull requests may give error-free builds but not necessarily when both pull requests are merged to master. The tests may not cover all the scenarios either